# Metric space equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

$$\exists c \quad \exists x\in X \quad \forall y\in X : d(x,y) \lt c \Longleftrightarrow \exists c \quad \forall x\in X \quad \forall y\in X : d(x,y) \lt c$$

I really have problems showing $"\Rightarrow"$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the $c$'s on both sides don't have to be the same. Thus, suppose the first statement holds. Then let $C = 2c$. Now let $y,z\in X$ be arbitrary. Then we have $$d(y,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(x,z) < c+c = C$$

Comment: Thats so simple but brilliant. Thank you!